# In Mono For Android, when specifying an mp3 file in OpenRawResourceFd, it plays the wrong file

Tags: c#, android, mono, media-player

I have a serious issue with Mono for Android (4.2.5).
I have a few mp3 files in my RAW folder, all set as AndroidResource.

This is my code:

```
idPlayer.SetDataSource(this.Resources.OpenRawResourceFd(Resource.Raw.m1991).FileDescriptor);
idPlayer.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
idPlayer.Prepare();
idPlayer.Start();
```

No matter which file is set (m1991 in this instance), it will always play one of the mp3s and only this one, when I deploy and run on my Galaxy Note. It would agree to play the one I want only if I delete all the other mp3s from the folder but the one I want to play.

Is this a known issue? do I do something wrong? I tried to debug and put a breakpoint to see what Resource.Raw.m1991 is and its a number that is different to the other Raw files.

Any help would really be appriciated!

Cheers
Guy

Answer (score 0):

see this article: http://mbcdev.com/2012/04/03/psa-assetfiledescriptor-and-filedescriptor-android-raw-resources/

"What seems to be happening is that the AssetFileDescriptor does describe the actual file but the FileDescriptor you get from that describes the entire blob in which your specific file is contained."